# Is it allowed to write "put someone into words"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, grammaticality-in-context

"put into words" is commonly used in English,
as in

> I cannot put into words how much I love him.
>
> I can't put my feelings into words.

But is it allowed to place a "person" as an object in this phrase?
as in

> "Amy was so unique that I couldn't put **her** into words."

Answer (score 2):

In a case like yours, I would use a different verb other than *put*.

> Amy was so unique that I couldn’t **describe** her in words.

One might say that the phrase “in words” is redundant in that sentence, and that it could be improved were it more concise:

> Amy was so unique, she was indescribable.

Nevertheless, the use of “in words” in such contexts is grammatical and not all that uncommon. The following are all quotes found in recent news articles:

> I [can’t describe in words](https://www.newsday.com/sports/high-school/gymnastics/suffolk-gymnastics-championships-2017-1.14817466) the feeling of winning. I’m very proud of my team.
>
> I [can't describe in words](http://www.knoxnews.com/story/sports/college/university-of-tennessee/football/2016/12/30/miracle-south-bend-highlight-johnny-majors/95920300/) the meaning of this win and the way it happened.
>
> I [can't describe in words](http://www.news-press.com/story/entertainment/2017/03/07/romance-racism-sun-south-pacific/98847986/) the kind of energy and dynamism our talented cast is bringing to this show.
>
> All I know is that it filled me with a rage I simply [can’t describe in words](http://www.cambridge-news.co.uk/news/cambridge-news/confessions-of-a-cambridge-punter-13497914).

Comment: [This might be good to read](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).